# Passing values from an md-dialog to a component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, material-design, mddialog

I am using angular 1.X framework and I ran into an issue using components.

I would like to use a component in a dialog or a panel.  But the problem I have is I cannot get the values I need in the component to be passed from the dialog controller.  I have attempted to by pass the dialog controller but that did not work either.

Here is a function I have that is in a controller:

```
ctrl.addAdjustments = function (event) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            template: '<add-adjustments-dialog close="$ctrl.close"></add-adjustments-dialog>',
            controller: function ($mdDialog) {
                var ctrl = this;

                ctrl.close = function (adjustment) {
                    $mdDialog.hide(adjustment);
                }
            },
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: event,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })
            .then(function (adjustment) {
                console.log('adjustment', adjustment);
            });
    };
```

As you see, I am using the components html tags in the template parameter which works.  I created a function expression in the dialogs controller and then am attempting to bind the variable to the component.

Here is my components controller:

```
  angular.module('app')
    .component('addAdjustmentsDialog', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/addAdjustmentsDialog/addAdjustmentsDialog.html',
        controller: addAdjustmentsDialogCntrlr,
        bindings: {
            close: '<'
        }
    });

/** @ngInject */
function addAdjustmentsDialogCntrlr() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.adjustment = {
        weight: 0,
        amount: 0,
        type: '',
        regions: []
    };

    console.log('close fnction', ctrl.b);

    ctrl.addAdjustment = function(){
        ctrl.close();
    }


}
```

Here I am trying to grab the binding and use it to send back a value as well.  The problem is the close variable I initially sent in, is `undefined`.

Any help would be grateful, thank you!